# Python: Split data set according to specific column

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am currently trying to build a classification model for which I am using [this](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~scottdw/stat541/PROJECT-DATA/DATA-Stat640/phoneme.data.txt) dataset for training and testing. It is extracted from the TIMIT database and contains digitized frequencies of five different phoneme classes. The frequencies are under the 256 columns labelled "x.1" - "x.256", while the phoneme class itself is labelled "g". Furthermore, there is also a "speakers" column identifying the different speakers.

My question is, is it possible to split this dataset into a 50:50 ratio of training and test data considering the speakers column? In fact, I want to divide the data so that any speaker is not in both sets, so that I do not validate the trained model with test data containing the same speakers that are already in the training data.

My approach was to extract all speakers from the original dataset using NumPy and make use of the `stratify` parameter of `train_test_split`:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(input_data, phonemes, random_state=42, test_size=0.5, stratify=speakers)
```

But this most likely is not the solution. I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can use pandas library of python to load the csv in to dataframe by using

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)`

then you can get all unique values of the column speaker by using

`arrayOfSpeaker = df['speaker'].unique()`

now you can easily use the arrayOfSpeaker to split your data into training and testing set.
Also i would recommend to first randomize the arrayOfSpeaker before slicing the array.

and i normally split the data into 70:20:10 ratio for train:validation:test. I didnt get the point of 50:50 split !